# Error message in multiple languages

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Good day everyone,

I have a doubt on my currently development, the thing is i've created a project using ntier and data application block for my data access layer so, i have a package named Entities where i create all my classes and i was trying to use error messages mapped to a resource file the problem is when i write the following code it marks up with error:

(Entity-Base-Clients)

```
public partial class Clients {

public Int32 Id {get;set;}
[Display(Name="Name", 
ResourceType=typeof(Resources.Language))] 
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings=false, 
ErrorMessageResourceName="Id", 
ErrorMessageResourceType=typeof(Resources.Language))] 
public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

In the following code it marks up error in "Resources" (which is the folder where i put my resource files) and "Language" is the resource file.

But when i do the exactly the same thing on the "Model" folder didn't marks up any error

(Model-Clients)

```
public Int32 Id {get;set;}
[Display(Name="Name", 
ResourceType=typeof(Resources.Language))] 
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings=false, 
ErrorMessageResourceName="Id", 
ErrorMessageResourceType=typeof(Resources.Language))] 
public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Do i have doing something wrong? am i missing a reference or configuration of the RF?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
[Display(Name = "Name"), Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName ="nameHasToBeGiven")]
        public string name { get; set; }
```

this one is way easier

Answer (score 0):

This is an old problem. To solve it I deactivated the EDMX Code generation and I created external TT files to generate :
DomainLayer : Contains EF EDMX classes (with navigation)

DataLayer : Contains stuff to query data

```
[Serializable]
public partial class Contact : _DomainLayer_Base  
{
    #region Primitive Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets Id.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The Id.</value>
    public virtual int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets FK_Language.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The FK_Language.</value>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Foregn key of Contact
    /// 
    /// </remarks>
    public virtual int FK_Language
    {
        get { return _fK_Language; }
        set
        {
            try
            {
                _settingFK = true;
                if (_fK_Language != value)
                {
                    if (Language != null && Language.Id != value)
                    {
                        Language = null;
                    }
                    _fK_Language = value;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                _settingFK = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MetaDataLayer** : Contains EF Independant classes with data annotations linked to resources (without navigation)

```
    [Serializable]
    public partial class Contact_MetaData : _MetaDataLayer_Base
    {
        [Display(Name = "Ety_Contact_Id" , ResourceType = typeof(InnovaApp.Layers.ResourcesLayer.Properties.MetaDataResources))]
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "ErrMsgRequired",ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(InnovaApp.Layers.ResourcesLayer.Properties.Resources))]    
    public virtual int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [Display(Name = "Ety_Contact_FK_Language" , ResourceType = typeof(InnovaApp.Layers.ResourcesLayer.Properties.MetaDataResources))]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "ErrMsgRequired",ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(InnovaApp.Layers.ResourcesLayer.Properties.Resources))]    
    public virtual int FK_Language
    {
        get;
        set;

    }
```

MetaModels : Inside the portal, MetaModels are MetaData members containers. They contains data required by portal. Example :If you have a foreign key, the ForeignKey value will be in the MetaData but ListItems used to fill the lookup will be in the MetaModel.
EntityLayer : Contains EF EDMX

When I create a EF Query I prefix result with db :

When I use the data in the view, I use my MetaDataLayer :

```
public class ContactViewer_MetaModel : Contact_MetaData
```

To transfert data from DomainLayer to MetaDataLayer I Use Emit Mapper because My TT files guaranty same signature between Domain and MetaData.

```
toReturn = ObjectMapperManager.DefaultInstance.GetMapper<Contact, ContactViewer_MetaModel>().Map(dbContact);
```

and in the view :

```
@model InnovaApp.Layers.SecurityLayer.Models.MetaModels.Contact_MetaModel
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
<ol class="olMainForm">
    <li>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FK_Genre)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FK_Genre, Model.Genres)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FK_Genre)
    </li>
</ol>
```

You can find the full source here :

https://myprettycms.codeplex.com